# Does not show C# watch window value

Tags: c#, visual-studio, watch

VS2022 C# watch window internal error message

I would like to inquire about an issue where values cannot be calculated in the Watch window.

[image: Pic1]

[image: Pic2]

How to solve this?

Comment: Single-step one more time so the yellow highlight arrives at the start of a statement.

Comment: press “F10” to proceed one more time, the value is not calculated.

Comment: select the unsafe option as written in the answer, the calculation does not work in the watch window.

Comment: Hi,@K G. Could you share your version of Visual Studio? Have you tried the same project on other computers or other versions of Visual Studio? You can try these steps and see if it helps.1.Restart Visual Studio. 2.Reset Visual Studio Settings:  go to Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings. 3.Clean and Rebuild Solution: ensure that there are no build errors or inconsistencies causing issues with debugging. 4.Check for Third-party Extensions: If you have any third-party extensions installed in Visual Studio, try disabling them to see if they are causing conflicts with debugging.

Answer (score -1):

we had the same thing with VS,
you can right click the **Library** and under Build tick **Allow unsafe code** setting , it's works for us.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWc2p.png)

Comment: select the unsafe option as written in the answer, the calculation does not work in the watch window